# How to inspect different monitor contrast on standby resume?

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, monitors

I'm using an external 4K Monitor on my notebooks docking digital port.

Resuming from standbye results in a much brighter contrast compared to booting. In particular I notice the difference in Xorg applications (exwm, firefox etc.). In terminal I can't tell the difference.

I couldn't find any hints in Xorg.log entries.

Where would you inspect that behaviour?